# Soil chemical Anaylsis/CAL-P

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have added two levels of Phosphorus (P) to the soil, one at 30 mg/kg and the other at 130 mg/kg, representing low and high P levels, respectively. After thoroughly mixing the fertilizer with the soil, I analyzed whether the intended amounts of P were present in the soil. The analysis results are presented in a table, and I am seeking assistance in interpreting the data to ascertain the actual P content in these two soil conditions.I appreciate your help.

CAL-Extraktion
(P2O5 mg/100g)
Low P soil sample=6.57
High P=17.1

Comment: So you want to know what unit belongs to the numbers 6.57 and 17.1

Comment: Also, what does the fertilizer packet exactly mention for phosphorus analysis?

Comment: @Karl, units are already mentioned P2O5 mg/100 g.

Comment: @AChem Ah, got it. 6.57 mq P2O5 equivalents per 100g soil. Well, that's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first sample of soil has $6.57$mg $\ce{P2O5}$ in $100$ mg soil, or $65.7$ mg $\ce{P2O5}$ in $1$ kg soil. As $\ce{P2O5}$ contains $43.6$ % P, the soil contains $0.436 · 65.7$ mg P = $28.5$ mg P in $1$ kg soil.

The second sample of soil has $17.1$ mg $\ce{P2O5}$ in $100$ mg soil. $17.1$ mg is $2.61$ times $6.57$ mg. So this sample contains $2.61$ times as much P atom, or $2.61·28.5 = 74.55$ mg P in $1$ kg soil.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from your analytics contractor means if all the phosphorous in 100 g of your low P sample was turned into $\ce{P2O5}$ and separated, it would amount to 6.57 milligrams.

To turn that number into "amount of pure P per 100g", you simply multiply by the mass fraction of P in $\ce{P2O5}$, i.e. with the relative molecular weight of 2 $\ce{P}$ and $\ce{P2O5}$, which is $2 \times 30.97 / 141.96 \approx 0.4$.